# How to collate sysname in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run a query to drop server logins coming from windows and recreate them. I run this query to drop logins and it works fine

```
USE master
SELECT 
       'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = ' + 
       '''' + [name] + '''' + ')' +
       ' BEGIN DROP LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' END; ' + 
       'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' FROM WINDOWS; '
FROM sys.server_principals  
WHERE type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_GROUP' , 'WINDOWS_LOGIN')
```

But the following query

```
USE master
SELECT 
       'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = ' + 
        spr.default_database_name
       + 'GRANT ' + spe.permission_name  + ' to ' + QUOTENAME([name])
       + CASE WHEN spr.default_database_name IS NOT NULL
            THEN ' WITH DEFAULT DATABASE = ' + spr.default_database_name
            ELSE 
            ''
        END
FROM sys.server_principals spr INNER JOIN 
     sys.server_permissions spe  ON spr.principal_id = spe.grantee_principal_id
WHERE spr.type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_GROUP', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN')
```

is returning this error

```
Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in SELECT statement.
```

So when I investigated the issue it is coming from the `sysname` column `default_database_name`
The query ran when I used `spr.default_database_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`
My three parts question is: Did I get the problem because of a row or because the column data type is `sysname`?. Is `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` the correct syntax for this scenario?. 
when I run this query

```
SELECT name, description
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
```

The results are showing many collations for different languages. So how did I get this error for a completely English database.

**Edit:** 
I ran these two queries to check the collation property for database and server

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'master', N'Collation')
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'Collation')
```

and the result in both of them was

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: My guess is that your database collation is different than the server collation.  (This isn't typical, but it's certainly not uncommon.)  If you run `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'MyDatabaseName', N'Collation')` and `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'Collation')` what are your results?

Comment: @DeadZone thanks for your comment. I will update my answer to include the results for those queries.

Comment: If you run `sp_help [sys.server_principals];` and look at the collation of the `default_database_name` column, does that match?

Comment: Yes. and it is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: That seems odd... You said that in order to fix the error, you had to forcefully collate the `default_database_name` column into *Latin1_General_CI_AI*.  But that's an Accent Insensitive collation and your default collation is Accent Sensitive.  That doesn't make sense to me.  Are you certain that you have that information listed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It may help to bring the default collate for database and server instance, changing the query as shown below:

```
SELECT 
       'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = ' + 
        spr.default_database_name COLLATE database_default
       + 'GRANT ' + spe.permission_name  + ' to ' + QUOTENAME([name])
       + CASE WHEN spr.default_database_name IS NOT NULL
            THEN ' WITH DEFAULT DATABASE = ' + spr.default_database_name COLLATE database_default
            ELSE 
            ''
        END
FROM sys.server_principals spr INNER JOIN 
     sys.server_permissions spe  ON spr.principal_id = spe.grantee_principal_id
WHERE spr.type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_GROUP', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone at MS has fixed the collation on sys.server_permissions.state_desc as Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS

I've tried on a number of instances (SQL 2016) and found the same problem. Putting "collate database_default" works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your question: Specify collation for two columns where you CONCAT

```
USE master
GO
SELECT 
   'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + 
' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = ' + 
    spr.default_database_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
   + 'GRANT ' + spe.permission_name  + ' to ' + QUOTENAME([name])
   + CASE WHEN spr.default_database_name IS NOT NULL
        THEN ' WITH DEFAULT DATABASE = ' + spr.default_database_name
        ELSE 
        ''
    END
FROM sys.server_principals spr INNER JOIN 
 sys.server_permissions spe  ON spr.principal_id = spe.grantee_principal_id
WHERE spr.type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_GROUP', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN')
```